# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.projects.inputData

Tags: java, android, firebase, search

I encountered this error and tried to find some solutions but no clue yet. The problem is I am trying to search the item on my phone, once find it, I will click on the item and then update it.

However I got "com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.projects.inputData" error.

BEFORE I click update, my firebase looks like:

[image]

AFTER I updated item, it looks like this and all the old data has been automatically removed:

[image]

Can someone help me out? Please.

```
package com.example.projects;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.transition.AutoTransition;
import android.transition.TransitionManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.GenericTypeIndicator;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class mainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference myRef;
    private FloatingActionButton main_fab;

    private TextView total_amount, total_buy_price;
    private RecyclerView mainRecyclerView;

    private String post_key = "";
    private String staff_name ="";
    private String size = "";
    private String material = "";
    private String colour = "";
    private String notes = "";
    private String type = "";
    private int money = 0;
    private int number = 0;
    public int soldNumber = 0;
    public int soldPrice = 0;

    ArrayList<inputData> dataList;
    SearchView searchView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://stuff-management-app-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app");
        mainRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.main_recyclerview);
        searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);

        mainRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mainRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        total_buy_price = findViewById(R.id.totalBuyPrice);
        total_amount = findViewById(R.id.main_total_records);
        myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("stuff records");
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                int totalRecord = 0;
                int totalBuyPrice = 0;
                dataList = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot snap: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    inputData data = snap.getValue(inputData.class);
                    totalRecord += data.getNumber();
                    total_amount.setText( totalRecord);
                    totalBuyPrice += data.getMoney();
                    total_buy_price.setText( totalBuyPrice);

                    dataList.add(snap.getValue(inputData.class));
                }
                AdapterClass adapterClass = new AdapterClass(dataList);
                mainRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    search(newText);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void search(String str) {
        ArrayList<inputData> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(inputData object : dataList){
            if (object.getStaff_name().toLowerCase().contains(str.toLowerCase())){
                myList.add(object);
            }
        }
        AdapterClass adapterClass = new AdapterClass(myList);
        mainRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClass);
        adapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private int getIndex(Spinner spinner, String myString){
        for (int i=0;i<spinner.getCount();i++){
            if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equalsIgnoreCase(myString)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    private void updateInfo() {
        AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_page, null);

        myDialog.setView(mView);
        final AlertDialog dialog = myDialog.create();

        final Spinner itemSpinner = mView.findViewById(R.id.input_size_spinner);
        final TextView input_name = mView.findViewById(R.id.input_record);
        final EditText input_price = mView.findViewById(R.id.input_price);
        final EditText input_number = mView.findViewById(R.id.input_number);
        final EditText input_description = mView.findViewById(R.id.input_description);
        final EditText input_material = mView.findViewById(R.id.input_material);
        final Spinner colourSpinner = mView.findViewById(R.id.input_colour_spinner);
        final EditText input_types = mView.findViewById(R.id.input_type);
        final Button delBtn = mView.findViewById(R.id.input_cancel);
        final Button updateBtn = mView.findViewById(R.id.input_save);
        final Button sellBtn = mView.findViewById(R.id.button2);

        input_price.setText(String.valueOf(money));
        input_description.setText(notes);
        input_name.setText(staff_name);
        input_material.setText(material);
        colourSpinner.setSelection(getIndex(colourSpinner, colour));
        input_types.setText(type);
        input_number.setText(String.valueOf(number));
        itemSpinner.setSelection(getIndex(itemSpinner, size));

        //sold
        final EditText sellNum = mView.findViewById(R.id.sellAmount);
        final EditText sellPrice = mView.findViewById(R.id.sellMoney);

        sellNum.setText(String.valueOf(number - 1));
        sellPrice.setText(String.valueOf(soldPrice));

        String sellNumber = sellNum.getText().toString();
        String sellPri = sellPrice.getText().toString();


        String[] colourr = new String[]{};
        final List<String> colourList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(colourr));
        // Initializing an ArrayAdapter
        final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, R.layout.spinner_item, colourList);
        myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("user_define_colour");
        // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                colourList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<String>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<String>>() {
                    };
                    ArrayList<String> value = child.getValue(t);
                    colourList.addAll(value);
                    spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
        colourSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
        // ----- retrieve colour from firebase

        myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("stuff records");      
        updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                number = Integer.parseInt(input_number.getText().toString());
                notes = input_description.getText().toString();
                money = Integer.parseInt(input_price.getText().toString());
                staff_name = input_name.getText().toString();
                material = input_material.getText().toString();
                colour = colourSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                type = input_types.getText().toString();
                size = itemSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if ( number == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                inputData data = new inputData(staff_name, size, material, colour, notes, Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(money)), Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number)), post_key, type);
                myRef.child(post_key).setValue(data).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(mainActivity.this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });      
    }


    public class AdapterClass extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterClass.myViewHolder> {
        ArrayList<inputData> dataList;

        public AdapterClass(ArrayList<inputData> dataList) {
            this.dataList = dataList;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public AdapterClass.myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_retrieve, parent, false);
            return new AdapterClass.myViewHolder(view);
        }

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<inputData> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<inputData>()
                .setQuery(myRef,inputData.class)
                .build();

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterClass.myViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.description.setText(dataList.get(position).getNotes());
            holder.name.setText(dataList.get(position).getStaff_name());
            holder.money.setText(String.valueOf(dataList.get(position).getMoney()));
            holder.material.setText(dataList.get(position).getMaterial());
            holder.size.setText(dataList.get(position).getSize());
            holder.colour.setText(dataList.get(position).getColour());
            holder.type.setText(dataList.get(position).getTypes());
            holder.number.setText(String.valueOf(dataList.get(position).getNumber()));
            holder.main_mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {                
                    updateInfo();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return dataList.size();
        }

        public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            View main_mView;
            TextView name, number, money, material, size, colour, description, type;
            public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                main_mView = itemView;
                description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notes);
                name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.staff_name);
                money = itemView.findViewById(R.id.money);
                number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
                colour = itemView.findViewById(R.id.colour);
                material = itemView.findViewById(R.id.material);
                size = itemView.findViewById(R.id.size);
                type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.types);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is shown

```
inputData data = snap.getValue(inputData.class);
```

Comment: What I mean by update is just to modified the stuff number or price. But if I update, my data will be deleted and my app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

whenever new expense data comes in add it to main expense data list and notify adapter.

```
expenseArrayList.add(new Data(new_item, new_notes, new_amount, new_date));
if (adapter == null) {
expense_recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
} else{
adapter.notifyItemInserted(expense_data_list.size()+1)
}
```